# a basic quetion in positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I found in a book that the author has described to check a positive definiteness of matrix is as follows

$\begin{pmatrix}
 a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
 a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
 a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Suppose this is a matrix.to prove this a positive definite we have to show only that 
$a_{11}$ ; $\begin{pmatrix}
 a_{11} & a_{12} \\
 a_{21} & a_{22} \\
\end{pmatrix}$;

$\begin{pmatrix}
 a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
 a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
 a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\\
\end{pmatrix}$

has positive determinant.
I know the method of reducing a matrix in its normal form, to check the positive definiteness. So my question is how this method becomes same to that one which I have mentioned?

Comment: can somebody edit the matrices , and please tell where I am typing wrong?

Comment: For subscripts type \$a_{ij}\$ instead of \$a_ij\$. For the matrices don't close the $ before the \end{pmatrix} command. Again: what is the question?

Comment: Thanks, just now I have edited my question

Comment: This is called [Sylvester's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion). A proof can be found on the link.

Comment: I fixed those errors as outlined by Git Gud, except the meaning of the middle line is not familiar to me so you may want to check that says what you want it to...

Comment: I wanted to say that I know a method to check a matrix is positive definite or not, and that method is reduce a marix to its normal form and check the signature of this matrix.If signature and rank are same then the matrix is called positive definite. But today I found this method which is new to me, so I doubt it.

Comment: @Git Gud...the link is very useful, you may write an answer, then I can accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [Sylvester's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion). A proof can be found on the link.

**Edit:** As asked by the OP, here are some remarks:

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} &\cdots &a_{1n}\\
\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\
a_{n1} &\cdots &a_{nn} \end{pmatrix}\in \mathcal M_{n\times n}(\Bbb C)$, for some $n\in \Bbb N$ and for every $t\in [n\textbf{]}$ define $A_t=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} &\cdots &a_{1t}\\
\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\
a_{t1} &\cdots &a_{tt} \end{pmatrix}$.

It is true that $A$ is negative definite if, and only if, $(\forall t\in [n\textbf{]})\left((-1)^t\det (A_t)>0\right)$.

Also $A$ is positive semidefinite if, and only if, all its submatrices have non-negative determinants.

Comment: What can you say about indefinite and negative definite matrix.Can we say something from this criterion?

Comment: @analysis89 I added some stuff to the answer.